# StdIn for Reading Inputs Hacker Rank Challenges

Tags: python, python-3.x

One thing that has frustrated me the most from the Hackerrank challenges is the part of reading inputs for the functions through `stdin`.

Hackerrank inputs generally have a `\n` delimiter, which is provided through `sys.stdin`. I want to know an efficient way to read the inputs and split them into a `list`. An example follows:

**Input:**

```
3 2
1 5 3
3 1
5 7
```

I want to read each line into a separate `list`. Below is my attempt:

```
import sys

arr = sys.stdin.readlines()[1].split()
arr = list(map(int, arr))

A = sys.stdin.readlines()[2].split()
A = set(map(int, A))

B = sys.stdin.readlines()[3].split()
B = set(map(int, B))
```

I'm getting following error:

```
A = sys.stdin.readlines()[2].split()
```

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why `IndexError` on `[2]` where as `[1]` works? Is there a better way to read such `stdin` inputs using loops?

Comment: Do you know the number of lists you'll need? I mean, do you know that for a particular question, you will need some specific number of lists?

Comment: Yes, I will need three lists starting from line 2.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are getting the error is that `readlines` is consuming all your input on the first call. That means that the second time you call it, there's nothing there.

To make a 2D list of all the inputs, you have to work with the first call:

```
data = [line.rstrip().split() for line in sys.stdin.readlines()]
```

You may as well convert to integers up front:

```
data = [[int(x) for x in row] for row in data]
```

Now

```
arr = data[0]
A = set(data[2])
B = set(data[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to input 3 lists(you know there will be 3 lists), then you can try the following:

```
myList1 = []
myList2 = []
myList3 = []

inStr1 = input()
inStr2 = input()
inStr3 = input()

for i in inStr1.split(" "):
    myList1.append(int(i))
for i in inStr2.split(" "):
    myList2.append(int(i))
for i in inStr3.split(" "):
    myList3.append(int(i))
```

Here is a sample output I got:
[image]